# How can I plot an axis on MatPlotLib in terms of text, not numbers, taken from a CSV file?

Tags: python, csv, graph, matplotlib, plot

I have a .csv file that looks something like this (small sample, disregard the periods):

```
Year | Month | Carrier | Elapsed Time

1987 | 10.......|UN.......|15

1987 | 11.......|AM.......|17

1987 | 12.......|HK.......|20
```

I'm plotting a 3D graph in MatPlotLib (Python), where the z-axis (vertical axis) is Elapsed time, the x-axis is the month, and the y-axis is the carrier. If I'm not mistaken MatPlotLib only allows the values of each axis to be an integer and not a string. That's where the problem lies: the carrier values are strings, or letters, such as UN, AM, and HK. My code so far is:

```
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')

readFile = open('/home/andrew/Downloads/1987.txt', 'r')
sepFile = readFile.readlines()[1:50000]
readFile.close()

rect = fig.patch
rect.set_facecolor('white')

X = []
Y = []
Z = []

for plotPair in sepFile:
    xAndY = plotPair.split(',')
    X.append(int(xAndY[1]))
    Y.append(str(xAndY[2])) #Putting str() instead of int() didn't solve the problem
    Z.append(int(xAndY[3]))

ax.scatter(X,Y,Z, c ='r', marker='o')

ax.set_xlabel('x axis')
ax.set_ylabel('y axis')
ax.set_zlabel('z axis')

plt.show()
```

I understand that I could just say x = [UN, AM, HK] but the problem with this is that the x list would not be taken from the .csv file. The Python program wouldn't know which point belongs to which carrier name. I want to be able to tell Python to search the column with the name of the carrier for each point and then be able to extract that information so it can plot successfully from the csv file as shown in the picture:

[3D Graph Skeleton](http://postimg.org/image/6u9cnpf9h/)

I'm still a newbie and getting the hang of Python so I thank you so much for taking the time to answer. Your help is seriously appreciated.

Comment: You could try using bar3d. I think this would allow labels.

Comment: Hi Bensciens, actually I wanted more of a "meshed" 3D graph like such: http://houbysoft.com/hc/hc-graph3d.png. But thank you so much for the recommendation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would make the Y axis a range of integers, and then set the yticklabels using your list of strings. Something like:

```
X = []
Y = []
Z = []
Ylabels = []

for plotPair in sepFile:
    xAndY = plotPair.split(',')
    X.append(int(xAndY[1]))
    Y.append(range(len(xAndY[2]))
    Ylabels.append(str(xAndY[2]))
    Z.append(int(xAndY[3]))

ax.scatter(X,Y,Z, c ='r', marker='o')

ax.set_xlabel('x axis')
ax.set_ylabel('y axis')
ax.set_zlabel('z axis')

ax.set_yticks(Y)
ax.set_yticklabels(Ylabels)
```

Comment: Ahh.. I see. I also wanted to mention that my CSV file has multiple rows of the same carrier, such as AM, HK, HK, UN, UN, HK, UN. Would the code above still work for this or would the graph have multiple tick labels of the same carriers? Would there be a solution to this? Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

Credit goes to the answer by Tom, this is just an adaptation.

Also, I'm pretty sure there are better answers out there but this should work for what you're doing.

```
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

X = {}
Z = {}

for plotPair in sepFile:
    xAndY = plotPair.split(',')
    label = str(xAndY[2])

    if label in x.keys():
        X[label].append(int(xAndY[1]))
        Z[label].append(int(xAndY[3]))
    else:
        X[label] = [int(xAndY[1])]
        Z[label] = [int(xAndY[3])] 

Y=0
for label in X.keys():
    ax.scatter(X[label],Y[-1]*np.ones_like(X[label]),Z[label], c ='r', marker='o')
    Y.append(Y[-1]+1)

ax.set_xlabel('x axis')
ax.set_ylabel('y axis')
ax.set_zlabel('z axis')

ax.set_yticks(Y)
ax.set_yticklabels(X.keys())
```

One bonus is that each carrier can have a different colour.